# can we use <? insted of <?php for start of php file, if not what is the use <? at start of php

Tags: php, html, boonex-dolphin

Currently i am working with an boonex dolphin project
inside the project soruce code many of the php file starts with `<?` instead of `<?php`  also i found out that in many of statements it used another statement like`<?= $start ?>`

`<td valign="top" align="justify"><?= $str ?></td>`

Comment: this called php short tag ..research for it and you will come to know its use

Comment: There is such thing as a documentation for php. Start reading it. You cannot develop in php without that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
"<?" : Short tags (you have to allow it from your server php.ini)
"<?php" : this represents php starting point.
"<?=" : it is just to show the output
example :

<?php $test= 'abc';?>
<?=$test?>
its output is abc
```